# Fast lossless, compressed streaming of packet capture between two servers?

Tags: networking, tcpdump, netcat, streaming

Suppose I am capturing packets on a remote host with `tcpdump` (more precisely, I'm doing it with an Endace card, which exposes a `tcpdump`-like utility called `dagsnap`).

What would be a fast way to stream the captured traffic in a lossless way onto my local host with inline compression?

The best naive approach I can think of is instead of writing to disk, have the remote host pipe the output to `lz4`, then pipe the compressed output onto a TCP connection to the local host established with `netcat`.

Is there a faster approach?

Comment: what are you capturing? if only certain metrics then something like netflow/sflow/ipfix might make more sense

Comment: Well, if you're streaming it through `ssh`, then `ssh -C` would be a simple & effective method.

Comment: @Patrick Didn't know about `-C` flag for `ssh`, that's cool, I'm not streaming it through `ssh` though.

Comment: @thrig I'm capturing all firewall traffic.